# Array not looking smooth in render along a path

Tags: texturing, modifiers, objects, shaders, path

I have an array modifier attached to a curve with a curve modifier. I want to make the crease in between each cube smooth but it's not working. I've applied the array modifier and smoothed the faces, verts, and edges and that didn't do anything. I've also applied a subsurf modifier with smoothing on which also didn't work. There is are 650 arrayed cubes scaled down on the z to make it as smooth as possible. The curve also has hundreds of vertices so that's very smooth too. I've searched everywhere for a solution and couldn't manage to find one. Any suggestions?

**Edit:** I just scaled the arrayed object down on the z axis making it really small then making the array count 5000 and the creases stayed the same. So the path needs more verts. I don't want to increase the verts on the curve, because it's already hard to edit and adding more verts will make it sooo much worse.

**Project File:** [stackexchange.blend](https://www.dropbox.com/s/14h75j7tsnu4yox/stackexchange.blend?dl=0)

(BTW I know the subsurf modifier is set to 0 in this picture I did try it with 3 subdivisions. Obviously didn't work.) 
[image]

Comment: have you press on the eye icon to make it visible? have you smoothed it? Also you should put the subsurf on the bottom

Comment: As said in the description I did smooth it, I didn't make the subsurf modifier visible in the view port to display the problem. And yes when I tried using the subsurf modifier to solve the issue I put it at the bottom of the stack and smoothed but that didn't work.

Comment: perhaps share your file

Comment: Yeah I'll link it in the post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that:

- Your curve has way too many vertices, so I guess it cuts your shape in small slices and annihilates the smoothing. You need to simplify it a lot: Convert it to mesh, delete most of the vertices with the *Checker Deselect* tool and *Dissolve Vertices*, come back to a curve, now in *Edit* mode, in the *Tools* panel, *Set Spline Type* to *Bezier*, and *Set Handle Type* to *Automatic* then *Aligned*.
- Or simply redo a spirale with less vertices.
- In the *Properties* panel > *Data* > *Shape*, give more *Resolution* to your curve. It has 12 by default but as it is a long curve you must increase the *Resolution* to 48.
- Add some horizontal edge loops to your object so that its arrays can bend along the curve.